# XNOR comparing with XOR Artificial Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, xor

I am arguing with my TA aboutt this question. I have researched the answer for XNOR and XOR independently for ANN to set up. So I found the answer for XOR and XNOR respectively are

> Y1 = (X1 AND ~X2) OR (~X1 AND X2) for XOR
>
> Y2 = (X1 AND X2) OR (~X1 AND ~X2) for XNOR

Yet can we just do a negation of XOR to get XNOR such as

> Y3 = ~ ((X1 AND ~X2) OR (~X1 AND X2))

I haven't found anything that using the implementation above so I could be wrong. If so let me know what you all think or any resources would be helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but I can tell you didn't read the "How do I ask a Question" section on this site before making your first post. You also didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site tour. This question seems to belong on mathoverflow.com. Please review stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting again.

Comment: I don't think it has to be in mathoverflow.com. Computer Science is inherently problem-solving so this can be a machine learning problem that falls under stackoverflow as well but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Respectfully disagree.  Good luck.